# Splide JS - Detect when the last slides is active

Tags: javascript, splidejs

I have a SplideJS slider with an amount of slides.
I need to perform an action when the last slider is active.

I check documentation but I didn't found any reference to this kind of event so I write a script to acheive that goal but i need some help

My code :

```
// Class for each slide
const splideSlide = document.querySelector('.splide__slide')

// Check if a next element sibling is available
if(splideSlide.nextElementSibling === undefined) {
        console.log("On last, I call aother action")
} else {
        console.log("Not last")
}
```

Comment: There's lots of events available, https://splidejs.com/guides/events/#event-list - `active` is probably the one you should look into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going with what @CBroe mentioned in the commends, `active` is the one that might work for you.

```js
const maxSlideIndex = document.querySelectorAll("li.splide__slide").length - 1;
secondarySlider = new Splide( '#example', {
    perPage    : 1,
    perMove    : 1,
    focus      : 'center',
    trimSpace  : false,
    autoWidth: true,
} ).mount();

secondarySlider.on("active",function(e){
  if(e.index === maxSlideIndex) {
    console.log("I'm the last one!");
  }
});
```

```css
#example {
  max-width: 650px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@4.1.4/dist/css/splide.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@4.1.4/dist/js/splide.min.js"></script>
<div id="example" class="splide">
  <div class="splide__track">
    <ul class="splide__list">
      <li class="splide__slide"><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400/EEE/FF343C" alt="Sample Image 01"></li>
      <li class="splide__slide"><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400/EEE/3FF43C" alt="Sample Image 02"></li>
      <li class="splide__slide"><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400/AAA/31FF3C" alt="Sample Image 03"></li>
      <li class="splide__slide"><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400/EEE/313FFC" alt="Sample Image 04"></li>
      <li class="splide__slide"><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400/AAA/3134FF" alt="Sample Image 05"></li>
      <li class="splide__slide"><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400/EEE/F1343F" alt="Sample Image 06"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

First thing I'm doing is getting the max index value, so that I'll know which slide is the last one. This could have been handled in other ways (for example `li.splide__slide:nth-child` and then getting the index of that one).

Next, after initializing the Splide slider, I'm attaching an [`active`](https://splidejs.com/guides/events/#active) event listener, and checking if the currently active slide's index is the same as the index of the last `li.splide__slide`.